# waiting forEach to finish using setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I wait for setState in a foreach to finish then show the render?

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    someArrOfObject.forEach(o => {
      this.setState({
        [`list_for_${o.id}`]: o.val
      })
    })
  }

  render() {

    const { selected_id } = this.state
    const selected_list = this.state[`list_for_${selected_id}`]

    return selected_list.map(o => <div>{o.val}</div>)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your state first and then call `setState` once.

Something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  state = someArrOfObjects.reduce((a, o) => {
    return Object.assign(a, {[`list_for_${o.id}`]: o.val})
  }, {})

  this.setState(state)
}
```

Comment: anyway to avoid using object assign?

Comment: You could replace it with `a[`list_for_${o.id}`] = o.val; return a`. What's the problem with Object.assign?

Answer (score 4):

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let newState = {};
    someArrOfObject.forEach(o => {
      {
        newState[`list_for_${o.id}`] = o.val;
      })
    })
    this.setState(newState);
  } 
  render() {

    const { selected_id } = this.state
    const selected_list = this.state[`list_for_${selected_id}`]

    return selected_list.map(o => <div>{o.val}</div>)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want React to render after all the changes to `this.state` has been made, then you don't have to do anything. React waits for several changes to be made to `this.state` before actually actually changing the `state`. Then only it the render function is called.

If what you mean is that you want to load every thing before `render()` is ever called, then what you want is `componentWillMount()` not `componentDidMount()`.

Hope that helps.